# Why can't I instantiate an inner class inside of main?

Tags: java

Why does the compiler complain here? It doesn't allow me to create a `Wrapper` object in main. MyList is a separate class. How do I create it ?

```
public class BinaryTree {
    Node root;

    class Wrapper {
        MyList.Node node;
    }

    class Node {
        Integer value;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main() {
        MyList list = new MyList();
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.node = list.getHead();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the compiler complaint.

Comment: -1 For not posting the compiler error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690128/how-to-instantiate-non-static-inner-class-within-a-static-method

Comment: FYI, this question has nothing to do with `main` and everything to do with `static`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrapper is an inner (non-static nested) class. In order to create an object it should be either static or access via outer class e.g. `new BinaryTree().new Wrapper()`

Answer (score 4):

`Wrapper` needs to be declared static:

```
static class Wrapper
```

Have you thought about moving all these classes into separate files?

(This is assuming that your `main` method is in `BinaryTree`. If not, you'll also need to apply what Preet Sangha suggested.)

Answer (score 1):

`Wrapper` is a non-static inner class of `BinaryTree`. There are two ways to create an object of Wrapper:

1. Make `Wrapper` static and create the objects of `Wrapper` directly as `Wrapper wrapper =  new Wrapper();`
2. Instantiate an object of the outer class i.e. `BinaryTree` and using the object of `BinaryTree`, create an object of `Wrapper` as follows:

:

```
 BinaryTree binary = new BinaryTree();
 Wrapper wrapper = binary.new Wrapper();
```