# Can a static nested class be instantiated in Java?

Tags: java, static, nested, instantiation

From Oracle's Java [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) I've found this text:

> As with class methods and variables, a static nested class is associated with its outer class. And like static class methods, a static nested class cannot refer directly to instance variables or methods defined in its enclosing class — it can use them only through an object reference.
>
> Note: A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.
>
> Static nested classes are accessed using the enclosing class name:
>
> OuterClass.StaticNestedClass
>
> **For example, to create an object for the static nested class, use this syntax:**
>
> **OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
>        new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();**

I thought it is not possible to instantiate a static class, so I don't really understand the sentence in bold.

Do you have any idea what it means?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You might be thinking of a non-static inner class, in which case you can only instantiate it through an already created instance of the outer class. Also, if you're familiar with C#, you cannot instantiate a static class in that language. This statement clears it up: "In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience."

Comment: My problem was not reloading the application in tomcat! It needed to reload the class files with the updated inner class as static. Not sufficient to just replace the server files - have to reload application :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You are either confusing `static` with `abstract` as kihero says, or you are muddling the concept with a class that has `static` methods (which is just a class that happens to have static methods).

A static nested class is just a nested class that doesn't require an instance of its enclosing class. If you are familiar with C++, *all* classes in C++ are "static" classes. In Java, nested classes are not static by default (this non-static variety is also called an "inner class"), which means they require an instance of their outer class, which they track behind the scenes in a hidden field -- but this lets inner classes refer to fields of their associated enclosing class.

```
public class Outer {

    public class Inner { }

    public static class StaticNested { }

    public void method () {
        // non-static methods can instantiate static and non-static nested classes
        Inner i = new Inner(); // 'this' is the implied enclosing instance
        StaticNested s = new StaticNested();
    }

    public static void staticMethod () {
        Inner i = new Inner(); // <-- ERROR! there's no enclosing instance, so cant do this
        StaticNested s = new StaticNested(); // ok: no enclosing instance needed

        // but we can create an Inner if we have an Outer: 
        Outer o = new Outer();
        Inner oi = o.new Inner(); // ok: 'o' is the enclosing instance
    }

}
```

Lots of other examples at [How to instantiate non static inner class within a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690128/how-to-instantiate-non-static-inner-class-within-a-static-method)

I actually declare all nested classes static by default unless I specifically need access to the enclosing class's fields.

Comment: Just to clear up terminology. Java has nested classes - static and non-static. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes. There's nothing like static inner classes.

Comment: @Swapnil Thank you for catching that. "Static nested classes", officially, for the `static` variety.

Comment: @JasonC is there any way to instantiate a private nested inner class from reflections, I need to achieve it in one of my unit tests.

Comment: Oh wow. That `o.new Inner()` pattern has never ever occurred to me. I would never have conceived of that as a valid expression. Far out, man.

Comment: So, simply said, the difference is, if Inner had methods, they would require an Outer object before they can be used, whereas StaticNested can be used without it. Also, what was not mentioned at all is what an Enclosing Instance is.

Comment: @Unknow0059 The enclosing instance is the instance of the associated enclosing class, where applicable. The enclosing class is the class that the inner/nested class is declared in.

Answer (score 27):

Static nested classes are themselves not static at all. In java, no class is static. Static keyword in static nested classes implies that it is another static member of the outer class. But it is just another raw class . Thats why we can instantiate this class

Comment: sorry but this answer is rather confusing

Comment: Great answer! This is the only answer so far that actually answers the question.

Answer (score 6):

You are confusing `static` with `abstract`. Abstract classes can not be instantiated. `static` is not a valid qualifier for top level classes, but the meaning for inner classes is the one you quoted.

Comment: He might also be confusing static methods with static classes.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you misunderstood the static class a little bit.
  It's true that every abstract class and interface cannot be instantiated, but you do can instantiate an static class.
  One thing you should notice is that **every static class is a nested static class**.
  You cannot just create a static class, as you can see:
  [try to create a new class in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4BxK.png)

A static class always belongs to the "parent class" which encloses it, and the difference between static and non-static class is:
  You can refer to the child static class just like a static property of the "parent class":

```
ParentClass.NestedStaticClass nestedstatic = new ParentClass.NestedStaticClass();
```

but you can only make reference to the non-static nested class by instantiating a parent class, like this:

```
ParentClass parent = new ParentClass();
ParentClass.NestedClass nested = parent.new NestedClass();
```

The difference is just like that between the static and non-static field.

Comment: Nested Static class is like a static property of parent class. All the static properties can be accessed with class name directly. Like Someclass.someStaticProperty or SomeClass.someStaticMethod. Here we are not using new key word to access static property or static method from parent class. Then why there is a need for new keyword here. "ParentClass.NestedStaticClass nestedstatic = new ParentClass.NestedStaticClass()"

Answer (score 1):

**Too long, didn't read: Every Concrete Class can be instantiated.**

We should not expect a Concrete Static Nested Class to function identically as Static variables and Static methods, when it comes to calling and instantiation.

What do I mean by that? When we create variables and methods they can be either static or non-static. The keyword in the previous sentence is "either".

Static meaning they belong to the class and we must call them directly, like this:

```
Class.staticVariable();
Class.staticMethod();
```

Non-static meaning they belong to an Instance of that Class and we must call them like this:

```
Class obj = new Class();
System.out.println(obj.nonStaticVariable);
obj.nonStaticMethod();
```

But here we are talking about a Class, not a variable or a method.
**Every Concrete Class can be instantiated.** Thus we should not expect a Concrete Static Nested Class, to not be instantiable.