# How to instantiate an Embeddable class?

Tags: java, class, instantiation, embeddable

I have a class which has an embeddable class:

```
public class User {
  ....
@Embeddable 
public static class UserPK{

@Column (name="idUser")
private Long idUser;

 @Column (name="idSubject")
private Long idSubject;

} 
@EmbeddedId
private UserPK userPK;


}
```

I need to instantiate "UserPK" but it's not working. Help Please!

I've tried to instantiate it as an inner class, as a single class.. it compiles but it doesn't creates the object.

Comment: `Embeddable` has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Are you able to understand that we can't help on a problem that is described by a simple "but it's not working"?

Comment: I believe those threads might help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836506/why-instantiation-of-static-nested-class-object-is-allowed , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293857/can-a-static-nested-class-be-instantiated-in-java

Comment: It's not working means: I've tried to instantiate it.. it compiled..and debugging i've looked for the object and i can't find it anywhere..  So i Thought maybe the problem is the embeddable..

Comment: Please show the code that reveals the problem (the code that is using your class).

Comment: The code it's easy, It's just a mapped class.. I'm trying to create an object of UserPK. I've tried to instantiate is as an inner class but compiler fails... I don't have a clue about it..

Comment: What we're trying to say is, post the error.

Comment: There is no error! Because the error which shows is produced because the object which i'm trying to create is not created.. So i Instantiate the object.. and it's like the lines i've developed are not written.. 

Now I've discovered i had an import "org.company.User.UserPK" so i've deleted the "UserPK" part and  now, allows me to instantiate as an inner.. but again.. it's like i haven't wrote anything.

Comment: You have declared `private UserPK userPK;` but you have not instantiated it.

Comment: And the code where you instantiate it?

Comment: I tried to instantiate in another class "UserServiceImpl".. But i don't think that's the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right about the import..

When i was trying to do:

> User.UserPK userpk = new User.UserPK();

It was failing because i had an import like this one:

> org.company.User.UserPK;

What I did to solve it it's let the import like this:

> org.company.User;

It allowed me to instantiate the class as an inner one.

**Thanks for those who helped me.**