# Accessing inner class from static outer util function

Tags: java, static

I have a class structure roughly like this:

```
final public class Util {
    private Util() {
        throw new AssertionError(); // there is not supposed to exist an instance
    }

    public static DataElem getData() {
        return new Util().new DataElem();
    }

    public class DataElem {
        // class definition
    }
}
```

The code for correctly generating an instance of the inner class was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690128/how-to-instantiate-non-static-inner-class-within-a-static-method) thread. But I didn't like that every time an inner class instance gets made, an instance from the outer one gets made first. And since I put the AssertionError into its constructor, it doesn't work.

Do I have to carry a dummy-instance around just to create instances from the inner class? Can't I make something like Util.DataElem work?

Comment: Add `static` to the class header for `DataElem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your inner class static

```
final public class Util {
    private Util() {
        throw new AssertionError(); // there is not supposed to exist an instance
    }

    public static DataElem getData() {
        return  new Util.DataElem();
    }

    private static class DataElem {
        private DataElem(){} // keep private if you just want elements to be created via Factory method
        // class definition
    }
}
```

and then initialize it like

```
new Util.DataElem();
```

Comment: what about this `return new DateElem()`

Comment: @Braj yes what about it ?

Comment: You should remove the `=` in `return = new Util().new DataElem();`.

Comment: Simply return `new DateElem()` there is no need to add the `Util` class name because it's already inside the `Util` class.

Comment: @JigarJoshi ... no it wasn't. The `=` is still an error.

Comment: ... Ok, now the problem is that you have to have a `new` before `DataElem();`. That line has to be either `return new Util().new DataElem();` or `return new DataElem();`.

Comment: @Jasha this is perfectly fine

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. But I cannot make the inner class static, as I mean to have several different instances of them.

Comment: Certainly you can have multiple instance of inner static class