# No object available for injection error when using bindFactory

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have the following implementation for a Jersey (2.18) application:

```
public class RootApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public RootApplication() {
        packages("com.foo.bar");

        register(new AbstractBinder() {

            @Override
            protected void configure() {       
                bindFactory(RepositoryFactory.class).to(Repository.class);

                // if I use following line instead of bindFactory it works
                // bind(OracleRepository.class).to(Repository.class);
            }
        });
    }

    public class RepositoryFactory implements Factory<Repository> {

        private final Repository repo;

        public RepositoryFactory() {
            this.repo = new OracleRepository();
        }

        @Override
        public Repository provide() {
            return repo;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(Repository repo) {
        }
    }
}
```

and get the exception below when hitting a service that injects Repository

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=Repository,parent=MeasureService,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,56464420)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.fidelity.pi.dashboard.rest.MeasureService errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.fidelity.pi.dashboard.rest.MeasureService
```

It all works if I comment out the `bindFactory` and use the commented-out bind.  Am I missing something in terms of the Factory implementation?  The exception seems to happen even before the `RepositoryFactory` constructor is hit.  I need the factory since I have some other initialization to do on the `OracleRepository` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I was able to reproduce the problem (with your incomplete information - i.e. missing injection point) was to try and inject `OracleRepository` instead of `Repository`. I don't have the exact reason why the injection fails, but I guess it's because you're binding `Repository` and not `OracleRepository`. If this is the problem, the simplest fix would be to bind the factory to `OracleRepository` or instead, simply inject `Repository`.

For injection of `Repository`, if you want to qualify different implementations you can do so by chaining `named` or `qaulifiedBy` to the binding, as in the example below (where I used `named` and annotate the injection point with `@Named`).

In the example I used the [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is the complete test. You can change the `@Named` between `"Sql"` and `"Oracle"` to see the difference.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class InjectionTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("test")
    public static class SimpleResource {

        @Inject
        @Named("Oracle")
        private Repository repo;

        @GET
        public String getRepoName() {
            return repo.getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(SimpleResource.class);
        config.register(new AbstractBinder(){
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(SqlFactory.class)
                        .to(Repository.class).named("Sql");
                bindFactory(OracleFactory.class)
                        .to(Repository.class).named("Oracle");
            }
        });
        return config;       
    }


    public static interface Repository {}

    public static class OracleRepository implements Repository {}

    public static class SqlRepository implements Repository {}

    public static class SqlFactory implements Factory<Repository> {

        @Override
        public Repository provide() {
            return new SqlRepository();
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(Repository t) {}
    }

    public static class OracleFactory implements Factory<Repository> {

        @Override
        public Repository provide() {
            return new OracleRepository();
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(Repository t) {}
    }

    /**
     * Change the `Assert` from "OracleRepository" to "SqlRepository"
     * when switching the `@Named` on the injection point.
     */
    @Test
    public void testInjectOk() {
        Response response = target("test").request().get();
        String respString = response.readEntity(String.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("OracleRepository", respString);
        System.out.println(respString);
    }
}
```

If you still have a problem, please post a complete single class test case like I have above that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the working sample.. after a bit of back and forth, I discovered the cause of the error, though I haven't completely worked out why.  Notice that my Factory class was not static, and that seems to be the issue.  It will similarly fail with the sample you have above once the Factory is not static.

Comment: Ahhh. I completely didn't catch that from your code. I thought it was two different files. Yes for inner classes they need to be static. I guess the class can't be instantiated by the framework if they aren't. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12690128/2587435) for some interesting reads on the subject