# Actionlistenerns and maybe classes idk (First attempt to Code)

Tags: java

Need Some help :

```
package FuckingGame;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public  class test1  {

static JFrame Miauz;
 static JLabel abc;
 static JPanel hs;
 static JButton test;
 static int a =0;


 public static void test2() {
Miauz= new JFrame();
Miauz.setTitle("Bestes");
Miauz.setSize(300,300);
 hs= new JPanel();
 test=new JButton("Press me");
 Druck druck= new Druck();
test.addActionListener(druck); 
 abc= new JLabel("Sie haben "+ a + " Geld");

 hs.add(test);
 hs.add(abc);
 Miauz.add(hs);
Miauz.setVisible(true); }   


public static void main (String args[]){
test2();}


public class Druck implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if( e.getSource() == test){
            a+=1;}
}
}
}
```

There is an error in the line :
Druck druck= new Druck();
but idk why ;-;
"No enclosing instance of type test1 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type test1 (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of test1)."
This is the errormessage.

Comment: You may want to provide a bit more detail about what you are trying to achieve. Also, what have you tried to do to fix this?

Comment: I want to increase a when u click on the button. i  dont even know what i tried cause this  is like my first attempt to try something ._.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is that `Druck` is nested in `test1`. You first need to have an instance of the outer class, before you create an instance of the nested class.
Consider this example:

```
public class Test {

    public Test(){
        System.out.println("Outer Class created");
    }

    public class TestInner {
        public TestInner(){
            System.out.println("Inner Created");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestInner inner = new TestInner(); // This is an error
        Test test = new Test(); // Initialization of the containing class
        TestInner inner2 = new TestInner(); // This is no error
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

Also take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12690151/5909613) into account.